# console.log ---> [object Promise]

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to do a simple fetch but I don't know how I can work with [object Promise].
I want to get all things by json and after display only todo.plainText.

I have 2 file:
FIRST ONE to declare different fetch functions
and the SECOND ONE to display different informations.

1°

```
const DEFAULT = "api/v1/todos"
const URL = "https://5f1563064693a600162756a6.mockapi.io/" + DEFAULT

export const getToDoList = () => {
   return fetch(URL)
     .then((res) => res.json())
}
```

2°

```
export default class ToDoList extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        todos: [],
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    const todos = getToDoList().then(data => { this.setState({ todos: data}) });
    console.log("vedo cosa mi torna la fetch: " + todos); //display [object Promise]
}


render() {
    const {todos} = this.state;
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <ul>
                {todos.map(todo =>
                    <li key={todo.key}>
                        {todo.plainText}
                    </li>
                )}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

What I need to change to display plainText for each elements??

Answer (score 0):

`Promise` calls the "callback" once the expected data is fetched. In your case, the response data. I would suggest you to go through it here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

I didn't get any response for `https://5f1563064693a600162756a6.mockapi.io/api/v1/todos/`.

You are not handling the errors on fetch call. Adding error handler will avoid avoid your confusion.